# Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:15.+

Tags: android, android-studio

i find 2 solutions for this problem, but both didn't work. So i decided to ask you.

I'm using Debian 8 Jessie and Android Studio 1.4

I just created new project and when i tried to start it i got an error:
"  Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:15.+  "
And gives me 3 option.

1) Install Repository and sync project

When i tried it i got an error like this:

```
Loading SDK information...
Ignoring unknown package filter 'extra-android-m2repository'Warning: The package filter removed all packages. There is nothing to install.
         Please consider trying to update again without a package filter.
```

And down of the window:

```
Install failed. Please check your network connection and try again. You may continue with creating your project, but it will not complete correctly without the missing components.
```

2) Show in File

It's my build.gradle dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:15.+'
}
```

Error in this line:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:15.+'
```

3) Show in Project Structure dialog

Dependencies windows is opened and about this line again:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:15.+'
```

**Tried Solutions:**

Firstly, i tried to download version sdk again. I deleted Android 4.0.3 and re-download again but still same error.

After that i tried to download support library which recommended in; [topic 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32914794/failed-to-resolve-com-android-supportappcompat-v7-15) , [topic 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31740393/failed-to-resolve-com-android-supportappcompat-v722-2-1). After i download Android Support Library, rev 23.0.1 still got same error.

After that i tried to solve my problem with fixing first option in error (install repository and sync project. And i found some topics again. I checked my HTTP Proxy section in Setting, already "No proxy" is selected.

So, i tried everything i found, but still i got this error. Someone can help me please?

Comment: If you downloaded 23.0.1, have you tried setting this version in gradle? `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'`

Comment: Wow, it really worked!

Comment: If my answer helped you, it would be nice to accept it. ;)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

After you downloaded the latest support library with your sdk manager, you can set that version in your gradle file.

If you downloaded 23.0.1 set it like this:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
```

**EDIT**:
Also note following hint, given by Android Studio, when using + in Version number:

> Avoid using + in version numbers; can lead to unpredictable and unrepeatable builds (com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.+)
>
> Using + in dependencies lets you automatically pick up the latest
>   available version rather than a specific, named version. However, this
>   is not recommended; your builds are not repeatable; you may have
>   tested with a slightly different version than what the build server
>   used. (Using a dynamic version as the major version number is more
>   problematic than using it in the minor version position.)

Comment: Hi, I've tried that. The error was gone, but it simply resulted in new 100+ "no resource found" errors instead. Based on what I'm reading, it's as if the support lib needs to somehow be rebuilt with a target sdk version of 15 but I am not sure how to do that in the new Android Studio... any ideas?

Comment: Never experienced this problem with android studio. First step would be to clean your projekt. `Build>Clean Project`

Comment: Maybe adding `compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'` might also help?

Answer (score 3):

Edit **build.gradle**

Replace **'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:15.+'** with **'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.0'**

**Sync It**

May be this will help you. If in case this will not work i.e. show error then see for installation of app-compat in **"%homepath%\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support\appcompat-v7"**

Search for the oldest version and put the version number at xx: 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:**xx**'

Answer (score 2):

I installed Java and Android Studio today.

When creating my first project with API level 15 as minSDK, I faced the same problem.

As far as I can tell, it seems the installation of the sdk works not pretty well. For me, API level 15 had only the SDK platform. API level 23 had platform and sources. I don't remember, which tools where installed.

To solve the problem, I started the sdk manager (old version), removed api level 15 completely and installed api level 23 as suggested. After that, a newly created project (again with minSDK 15) was properly created.

The difference in the `app/build.gradle` file is obvious.

Maybe this helps other people facing the same issues, or one of the gurus can further explain, what happened.

Kind Regards

Answer (score 1):

Got same errors.

Mac OSX

V. 10.9.5

Android studio 1.4.1

App:

Before:
android {
    compileSdkVersion 15
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

After:
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

Before:
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:15.+'
}

After:
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.o'
}

Above changes + Build >> Clean Project.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Go to Built tab select "Edit Built types" select properties tab and check built tool version it was 19.1.1 for me.
Then go to built.gradle change compile to   'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19+' . I changed to 19+ because my built version is 19.1.1 ; You have to select according to your built version(18+,19+,20+ like that).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try following solution:

In Android studio:
Go to File -> Project structure
Check the selected **Build Tools Version**.

update your build.gradle for app with selected build tools version.
for e.g. 19.1.0

After update, Run Clean.

Please refer below screenshot.[Project Structure-> Build Tools Types][1]

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error message when creating a project.

fail to resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:14.+

I notice that if I create a new project with support for 4.0.3 instead of 4.0, no error occurs.  I am using android studio 1.5.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

in my case, support and wearable versions were different, after making them exactly same, gradle build completed successfully.

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.google.android.support:wearable:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:11.0.4'
    provided 'com.google.android.wearable:wearable:1.0.0'
}
```